# On mobile screens, I have a disappearing white unwanted border

Tags: html, css

this is the outline of my problem.
On my [website](https://olingard.github.io/) 
when you view it on mobile platforms, initially there is a large white border which you can scroll into which is unwanted. Obviously, I have implemented the code:

```
html, body {  margin: 0px;  padding: 0px;}

body {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The kicker is that, once you scroll past the achievement section, the white border which is causing my issues disappears.

My question is, how do I remove this white border from the initial website? I have tried viewing the website on both the latest versions of chrome and safari on my `iPhone` and on the `Android` system.

Thanks for your time and I apologize if you need any extra code or if the answer is simple as I am a beginner programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being caused by the slide-in content that is being shown as the user scrolls down the page. Even though you cannot see it (`opacity:0`) the browser is still rendering the content, just off to the right of the screen. I'm not sure which property you've set to stop the page from zooming onto the body, but the end effect is that you can see the white border where the content comes out to.

The content you are hiding/showing is contained within a widget with the class 'timeline'. Add `overflow:hidden` to the `.timeline` css:

```
.timeline {
    margin-top: 8.75rem;
    overflow: hidden; /* New property */
}
```

Comment: Ah thank-you! I saw this problem but only thought to fix it by attempting to alter the transformations!